# How to get GPS coordinates from blackberry when logging into a website

Tags: javascript, blackberry, geolocation, gps

Im trying to do a website where a user will log into the website with a username and password with his blackberry example 9800 tourch. Then i want the web page to use the Blackberry's GPS to get the coordinates. Can someone please help me with some kind of code.

Thank you in advance.
M

Answer (score 1):

You can try these methods.

1. [Using HTML5 Geolocation in your Web or BlackBerry WebWorks applications](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Using-HTML5-Geolocation-in-your-Web-or-BlackBerry-WebWorks/ta-p/630406)
2. [javascript geo location framework for the mobile web](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried both of those links and both return 0,0 for the latitude and longitude on my blackberry curve (9330, OS 6.0).  This is very disappointing because I've been using #2 above for every other device.  After digging around for a nearly a day I found this to work on my blackberry (although I can't get the removeLocation handler to work.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="Javascript">
function removeLocation() {
    // dummy function since removeLocationUpdate requires a callback
    window.alert("location handler removed");
}
function getLocation() {
    window.alert("Your new position is " + blackberry.location.latitude + " degrees latitude and " + blackberry.location.longitude + " degrees longitude.");
    blackberry.location.removeLocationUpdate(removeLocation);
}

if(blackberry.location.GPSSupported) {
blackberry.location.setAidMode(1);
blackberry.location.refreshLocation();
blackberry.location.onLocationUpdate(getLocation);
} else {
alert('nope');
}

</script>
<p>detecting location....</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This script was found using help from the last post on this link:
http://www.blackberryforums.com/general-legacy-device-discussion/23544-7130e-gps-location-based-services-2.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

Note* replace: YOUR_DESTINATION_ADDRESS with an address in a format like: "147+Wyndham+Street+N+,+Suite+206,+Guelph,+On,+N1H+4E9"

```
<div id="Map" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var zoom = 11;
    function success(position) {

        var LAT = position.coords.latitude;
        var LONG = position.coords.longitude;
        $('#Map').append('<p>Current Latitude: ' + LAT + '<br/>Current Logitude: ' + LONG +'<br/><br/>Note* This may not display your exact location, but just your city. Works better on mobile devices</p>');


        var map  = '<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 600px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.ca/maps?source=s_d&saddr=' + LAT +',+' + LONG +'&daddr=**YOUR_DESTINATION_ADDRESS**&ie=UTF8&t=hz=' + zoom + '&output=embed"></iframe>';

        $('#Map').append(map);

    }

    function error(){
        /*Error Code*/
    }

    function MakeMap(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        } 
    }

    MakeMap();
});
</script>
```